# Generating random sample from csv file, whilst skipping rows with certain values

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to generate a random subsample of 5000 rows from a .csv file containing tens of thousands of rows. The df contains two columns: 'JPG' and 'NAME'.

I have generated a random subsample with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv(r'C:\filepath\data.csv', usecols = [7, 8])

sample = file.sample(n=5000)
print(sample)
```

However, now I wish to do the same, but including a for-loop that can do so whilst skipping any rows with the string ***'t3'*** in the ***'NAME'*** column.

Here's where I'm at, but stuggling to make it work:

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv(r'C:\filepath\data.csv', usecols = [7, 8])

sample = file.sample(n=5000)
for num in sample:
    if sample.loc[sample['NAME'] == 't3']:
        continue
print(sample)
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you filter out all the rows with the `NAME` t3 beforehand? Like:

```py
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv(r'C:\filepath\data.csv', usecols = [7, 8])
file_without_t3 = file[file['NAME'] != 't3']

sample = file_without_t3.sample(n=5000)
print(sample)
```

Comment: Very good point! I overcomplecated that, and got confused in the process. Thanks for the help Zhao! :)